# What does comma signify in a function definition?

Tags: php, functions, definition

From PHP manual:

```
array array_change_key_case ( array $array [, int $case = CASE_LOWER ] )
```

What does comma signify in a function definition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Comma is a separator between parameters in the parameter list.**

Comma is part of the parameter lists. Optional parameters are usually specified inside square brackets **in documentation** like so: `[, int $case = CASE_LOWER]`. Comma is added to specify that if you were to use the second optional parameter, you must have a comma separator as well.

The fact that comma is inside square brackets, means it's only required when you have more than one parameter.

**Another example with more optional parameters:**

```
array array_change_key_case ( array $array [, int $case = CASE_LOWER [, string $myValue = '' ]] )
```